# Can you glue backerboard to concrete then tile over?

Tags: concrete, walls, tile, backsplash

Want to know if you can glue backerboard to interior concrete wall for kitchen backsplash. Can’t drill as it’s a condo concrete wall. Concerned that tiles will shift as concrete wall shifts.
Thanks

Comment: Does the concrete wall have cracks in it or show any current signs of movement anywhere?

Comment: If the concrete wall shifts I think you're going to have bigger concerns than having a few tiles shifted. Plus any movement in the concrete will _also_ move backer board that is _glued_ to the concrete, thus moving the tiles right along with it.

Comment: Thanks Bryan’s-I can’t see the concrete wall to know if there are cracks etc.

Comment: Thanks FreeMan- it’s a concrete slab. Concern is that if there is shifting tiles on backsplash have nowhere to go but out and off.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can glue the backer to the wall. No matter what you do if the wall shifts there will be issues. Most the time if there is concrete I do not use backer unless there will be a large difference in surface height.

Comment: If you go the backer board route, use a good construction adhesive.+

Comment: Thanks to everyone that’s answered.the job is complete, now time will tell.

Comment: Thanks are ok but if any of the answers or comments are appropriate they should be upvoted or accepted , this helps others find an answer that worked.